# Best office programme for Ubuntu with Wacom support?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, libreoffice, wacom

Which is the best programme like LibreOffice Writer which has the option to use a Wacom pen tablet to draw in between the text in Ubuntu 14.04?

My main purpose is to take physics notes; I have tried Xournal and it is just basic do not have all the tools that are required like math etc. I like using Ubuntu and I do not want to use Windows and I am missing MS-Office and One Note, handwriting recognition etc.

Comment: Upvoted in the hope to see some answer, but I fear that `xournal` is the best app we have today. You can check if `xournalpp` (a fork of the former) can help you; it has mathtex integration for formulas.

Comment: This question would likely be a better fit for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use **Google Docs** inside Google Chrome. (Provided that you have decent Internet connection). It is possible to enable handwriting from your browser.

https://docs.google.com

You can add math and other miscellaneous functions with add-ons in Chrome

[Math add-on for Google doc](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmath/hhaencnpmaacoojogjkobikbmkhikjmm)

Answer (score 0):

I use krita to annotate pdfs. That won't do everything that you need it to, but you might find it helpful in some cases.